# how to browse the columns of an array in python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a csv file that i imported with pandas

```
file3 = 'C:/Users/asus/Desktop/spmf/lignes.csv'
names = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q']
ligne = read_csv(file3, names=names, delimiter=';')
array3 = ligne.values
```

I want to browse this table, and for each line I want to access to the values of its columns to retrieve them and use them in another method, so we need two nested loops "for", for lines and columns, but I dont know how to make them in python, and then for each column how to retrieve its value in a variable

this is an example of my file

```
5.0                         
1   7   11  13  14  16      
0   1   4   7   8   11  15  
0   1   3   4   5   7   11  13
0   1   3   4   5   7   11  13
0   1   3   4   5   7   11  13
```

Comment: Can you (a) provide some sample data in the format of your csv file; (b) indicate what type of logic you need to apply per row per column? The second question is because there may be a way to *vectorise* your logic which avoids these python-level loops.

Comment: i put an example in my question, for each line, I want to browse its column, so for example for this line 1 7 11 13 14 16 I want to put a for loop to access these values, and then each of these values is then used as an index in another array I have, so the problem now is how to browse the columns of the file

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to load a csv file and go through it row by row, column by column a quick dirty method is:

```
file3=open('C:/Users/asus/Desktop/spmf/lignes.csv')
for row in file3:
    for col in row.split(",")[:-1]:
        #do something with the row value
        print(col)
file3.close()
```

Although if you don't want to read to first line you can add
`file3.readline()`
before the for loops.